# Segmented regression with quadratic polynomial and a strightline

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to implement segmented regression as per this example [Segmented Regression, Breakpoint analysis](https://rpubs.com/MarkusLoew/12164).

Now, how can i implement it in such a way the second part will be quadratic polynomial and remaining other things same.

I tried the same by changing `Z= ~poly(DistanceMeters, 2)` however it didn't work.

Also, How can I get equations like

```
part 1: a1*x+b1
part 2: a2*x2**2 + b2*x + c1
part 3 :a3*x + b3
```

There are similar questions like this however they din't explain using segmented function.

Comment: Do you require the use of the `segmented` package, or would you be OK with just subsetting the dataset and building separate `lm` models for each segment?

Comment: Yes, because I want the breaks also to be calculated with some starting values like in the example

Comment: To be precise this the exact problem with exact data  http://stackoverflow.com/q/42643638/4729183

Comment: But there is no data in the example. Could you provide some artificial data similar to what you are working with?

Comment: @m-dz This is the actual data [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/su7el2njotm4oi0/data.csv?dl=0)

Comment: @ShankarPandala, did you find a way to build your model?

Answer (score 3):

I have two ideas, both with drawbacks. Maybe you can adjust one of them to your needs. Unfortunately cannot access Drive at the moment, so some artificial data used.

**1. "Manually" fit polynomial models**

Here you can specify whichever models you like, some segments can be lm's, some polynomials etc.

Code:

```
library(segmented)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# Data
set.seed(12)
xx <- 1:100
yy <- 2 + 1.5 * pmax(xx-35, 0) - 1.5 * pmax(xx-70, 0) + 15 * pmax(runif(100) - 0.5, 0) + rnorm(100, 0, 2)

dt <- data.table(x = xx, y = yy, type = 'act')
dt_all <- copy(dt)

# lm
lm_lin <- lm(y ~ x, data = dt)
summary(lm_lin)

# Find segments
lm_seg <- segmented(
  lm_lin, seg.Z = ~ x, psi = list(x = c(30, 80)))

# "Manual" lm's
breaks <- unname(lm_seg$psi[, 'Est.'])
lm_poly1 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 4), data = dt[x < breaks[1], ])
lm_2 <- lm(y ~ x, data = dt[x > breaks[1] & x < breaks[2], ])
lm_poly3 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 4), data = dt[x > breaks[2], ])

dt_all <- rbind(
  dt_all,
  data.table(x = xx, y = c(
    predict(lm_poly1),
    predict(lm_2),
    predict(lm_poly3)),
    type = 'lm_poly'
  )
)
```

**2. Fit a gam model using breaks from `segmented` and some splines**

Here you will get a smooth transition between segments, but you have much less control on what is happening.

```
# Using splines for smooth segments
library(mgcv)

spl <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cc", k = 12), data = dt, knots = list(xx = breaks))

# Plot
dt_all <- rbind(dt_all, data.table(x = xx, y = predict(spl), type = 'spl'))
ggplot(dt_all, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(size = 1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ type) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Both can be done using e.g. `list()` and `lapply()` to automate a bit (for varying number of breaks etc.).

**Edit:**

By changing arguments of `poly` and `s` you can get slightly "better" fitting models, but for `gam` errors on the edges are quite big, see for `degree = 6` and `k = 30`:

[image]